# How can I plot a 3d vector fast in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, arduino, accelerometer, gyroscope

I'm working on a project which includes use of accelerometer and gyroscope to get the orientation an object. I can pass the 3d orientation vector from arduino to matlab via serial communication.

I want to plot the vector in matlab to make real time analysis. I'm using `quiver3d` and `drawnow` functions in a loop to plot the vector but `quiver3d` function is very slow so I can see the orientation of object after like 20 seconds later.

Is there any way to plot 3d vectors faster?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`quiver` plot may be too much for plotting only one vector in 3-D. You can achieve a similar plot by using a simple `plot3` such as the one plotted below.

In this plot, the origin of the vector is the blue dot, and the direction is given by the red line.

[image]

The code

```
%v is the direction of the vector (3 cartesian coordinates)
v = sort(randn(100,3));
v = bsxfun(@rdivide,v,sqrt(sum(v.^2,2)));

%xyz the origin of the vector
ind = linspace(-pi,pi,100);
x = cos(ind);
y = sin(ind);
z = ind;

%the plotting function
figure
for ii = 1:numel(ind)
    plot3(x(ii),y(ii),z(ii),'bo'); %origin in blue
    set(gca,'XLim', [-3 3], 'YLim', [-3 3], 'ZLim', [-3 3]);
    hold on;
    hl = plot3( linspace(x(ii), x(ii)+v(ii,1),10),  ...
                linspace(y(ii), y(ii)+v(ii,2),10),  ...
                linspace(z(ii), z(ii)+v(ii,3),10),  ...
                'r'); %direction in red
    view(80,10);
    pause(0.1);
    %clf
end
```